# Creating activation code for my android app

Tags: android, security, activation

I have an app that comes with a physical device. I want that only the people who bought the device will be able to use the App. The current idea is to have an activation code that will come with the device which the user will input to start using the app.

How do I implement such a behavior in my app in a secure way?

Comment: Is the app useful without the device?

Comment: Could be with a Chinese knock off...

Comment: If it's on the phone, then you must assume that it is insecure.  Unless you involve a server which you can control, anything you do can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the IMEI number in the code and if It is matching your product, then go forward with the next activity.